# Не работает динамическое добавление input в уже добавленном input по событию keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать автодобавление input на страницу по нажатию клавиши Enter.

HTML:

```
<div id="block">
<input type="text" class = "editable"><br>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".editable").keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
      $(this).after("<input type='text' class='editable'><br>");
  } 
})
```

Первый раз input вставляется корректно. Если же в нем текст и нажать Enter, то ничего не происходит.
Не подскажете, как это побороть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function keyupHandler(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var $newInput = $("<input type='text' class='editable'><br>").keyup(keyupHandler);
    $(this).after($newInput);
  }
}  
$(".editable").keyup(keyupHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <input type="text" class="editable"><br>
</div>
```